# Failed to find definition for url(#paint0_linear) in flutter

Tags: flutter, svg, flame

I am using `flame_svg: ^0.0.1` package from flutter for rendering svg when i try to load the svg it gives the below error

```
flutter: The following assertion was thrown in _getDefinitionPaint:
flutter: Failed to find definition for url(#paint0_linear)
flutter: This library only supports <defs> and xlink:href references that are defined ahead of their
flutter: references.
flutter: This error can be caused when the desired definition is defined after the element referring to it
flutter: (e.g. at the end of the file), or defined in another file.
flutter: This error is treated as non-fatal, but your SVG file will likely not render as intended
```

Comment: Well, is the definition after the element as the error suggests?

Comment: i did not get that @RobertLongson, Thanks

Comment: https://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/IG/resources/svgprimer.html#patterns

Comment: Can you share the svg file in question? There's likely an issue with it...

Answer (score 13):

Move `<defs>` tag below the end of opening `<svg>`. It will solve Svg Rendering
error especially when you use gradient svg in `flutter_svg` package.

```
<svg>
  <defs></defs>
   <path></path>
</svg>
```

Explaination:

According to [javatpoint](https://www.javatpoint.com/svg-defs-element)

> The SVG  element is used to embed definitions that can be reused inside an SVG image.

So these **svg plugins** in flutter reads the svg code sequentially. Now if it doesn't finds the definition it throws an error. That's why the definition needs to be at the top

Comment: It worked magically. 

Comment: What I found is. `The SVG <defs> element is used to embed definitions that can be reused inside an SVG image`. So these `svg plugins` in flutter reads the svg code sequentially. Now if it doesn't finds the definition it throws an error. That's why the definition needs to be at the top

Comment: Thanks man. It just worked, and its the solution that Figma users need 

Answer (score 1):

Go to your SVG file and you will find the `<def>` tag at the bottom of the JSON. you need to put that on the top after the `<svg>` tag.

```
    <svg width="329" height="248" viewBox="0 0 329 248" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <defs>
    <radialGradient id="paint0_radial_4273_1881" cx="0" cy="0" r="1" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" gradientTransform="translate(419.65 197.242) scale(415.687 359.777)">
    <stop stop-color="#C760E0"/>
    <stop offset="0.5" stop-color="#9441A8"/>
    <stop offset="1" stop-color="#6C297C"/>
    </radialGradient>
    </defs>
.....
<\svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

As suggested on the logs provided, it seems that the SVG that you're trying to display is unsupported:

```
flutter: This library only supports <defs> and xlink:href references that are defined ahead of their 
flutter: references.
```

Make sure that the SVG that you're trying to load has the supported tags. You can try loading a different SVG and see if it can be displayed.